# Find derivation and draw a graph and its derivations

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I tried to search how to solve this type of problem, but I haven't found anything.

$f(x)=|x|$

$f(x)=|cos x|$

Task is to find derivation and draw a graph and its derivation; my idea was to solve it by limits, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it as

$$ |\cos x| = \begin{cases} \cos x, & \cos x \geq 0 \\ - \cos x, & \cos x < 0 \end{cases} $$

You can find find the derivative using the usual rules as long as $\cos x \neq 0$ as these points are problematic. Indeed, Let $x= \frac{ \pi }{2}$. We see that

$$ \lim_{x \to \pi/2} \frac{ |cos x | - |\cos \pi/2| }{x - \pi/2} = \lim_{x \to \pi/2} \frac{ |cos x |  }{x - \pi/2}  $$

And,

$$ \lim_{x \to \pi/2^+} \frac{ \cos x }{x - \pi/2} = + \infty $$

$$ \lim_{x \to \pi/2^-} \frac{ \cos x }{x - \pi/2} = - \infty $$

Implying the non-differentiability at points $x$ for which $\cos x = 0$. The first example is simple. Notice that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ |x| }{x} $ does not exist.

Comment: What if I would have $f(x)=x*|x|$ then the result is $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ |x|*x }{x} $ so it doesnt exist again?

Comment: In that case $f(x)  = x^2 $ if $x \geq 0$ and $-x^2  $ if $x<0$

Answer (score 0):

Just use piecewise definitions, taking the derivative of each:

$$|x|=\begin{cases} x & x\ge 0 \\ -x & x<0 \end{cases}$$
So $$|x|'=\begin{cases} 1 & x\ge 0 \\ -1 & x<0\end{cases}$$
Now do the same for $|\cos(x)|$

Comment: how about $|0|'$

Comment: so for $$|cos x|=\begin{cases} cos x & cos x\ge 0 \\ -cos x & cos x<0 \end{cases}$$$$|cos x|'=\begin{cases} -sin x & x\ge 0 \\ sin x & x<0\end{cases}$$ ?